# How to make get_theme_mod work with AJAX in the customizer preview

Tags: ajax, theme-customizer, options, get-template-part, get-theme-mod

Is it possible to make the get_theme_mod work after refresh in the customizer preview pane when it's being called inside a template part by AJAX?

I have a theme that loads the posts on scroll (infinite scroll) and everything works except it doesn't output the updated theme mods in the customizer preview. It only outputs the new theme mods when I hit the save button.

Any idea how to make it update after a refresh as well?

**My control settings:**

```
'id'        => 'show_caption',
'type'      => 'select',
'section'   => 'caption',
'transport' => 'refresh',
'default'   => 'top',
'choices'   => array(
  'top'    => __( 'Top', 'my-domain' ),
  'bottom' => __( 'Bottom', 'my-domain' ),
),
```

**InfiniteScroll.php:**

```
class InfiniteScroll {

  private $query;

  public function __construct( WP_Query $query ) {
    $this->query = $query;
  }
  
  public function register() {
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_infinite_scroll', array( $this, 'handleAjax' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_infinite_scroll', array( $this, 'handleAjax' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueueScripts' ) );
  }

  public function getPosts() {
    ob_start();

    $this->query->query( $this->getData() );

    if ( $this->query->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $this->query->have_posts() ) {
        $this->query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content' );
      }
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return ob_get_clean();
  }

  public function handleAjax() {
    if ( ! check_ajax_referer( 'infinite-scroll-ajax', 'nonce' ) ) {
      wp_die();
    }

    wp_send_json_success( $this->getPosts() );

    wp_die();
  }
  
  // ...

}
```

**content.php:**

```
echo get_theme_mod( 'show_caption', 'top' );
```

`Ajax request before customize_save:`

[image: Before]

Comment: maybe include the customizer setting and relevant code to your question. look into the `transport` argument for the setting it is possible to use refresh or postMessage for that and tutorials around for both.

Comment: @majick Thanks for your fast replay. Sorry for my vague description. I've been searching for this specific issue but didn't find anything related. I've updated my question with code examples but not sure if it's relevant to the issue since I'm stuck.

Comment: Ajax requests should include the Customized preview state applied to their responses as of 4.7. You can see the logic in `customize-preview.js` where it hooks in with `jQuery.prefilterAjax()`: https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6f4866bada9be5ff6fb4cde885aafe1e047dc267/src/wp-includes/js/customize-preview.js#L395-L413

Comment: Do note however that it is not recommended to use admin-ajax on the frontend because the requests are not cached.

Comment: @WestonRuter I found some documentation here: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/10/12/customize-changesets-technical-design-decisions/ I've now added the UUID to my URL, like this `'.../admin-ajax.php?customize_changeset_uuid=' + uuid`. Still not working.

Comment: @michael that is unnecessary because the `prefilterAjax` I mentioned should be injecting it for you. I suggest opening console and running `wp.customize.dirtyValues()` to see that the settings are actually dirty, and then open the network console to see the Ajax requests to verify that the `customize_changeset_uuid` param is getting included along with any `customized` POST data. And lastly, look at the `customize_changeset` post itself in the DB to see that has your written changes to it.

Comment: @WestonRuter I used the Fetch API but have change to jQuery for now. I've made some progress, see my edit of attached screens. The calls before `customize_save` have the `customized` data included, but no change on `get_theme_mod`. The calls after `customize_save` don't have the `customized` data included, but `get_theme_mod` prints the updated setting. Do you know why that's happening?

Comment: @michael That's great. Yeah, thanks for explaining that the Fetch API is being used. That explains why the customized state wasn't getting injected. We'll need to look at ways to injecting the customized state into requests made via Fetch or raw XHR instead of jQuery Ajax. Now, as to why the the requests include the customized values in the request before `customize_save` but not after is because once the save happens then the state has been written into the changeset and there is no need to include the dirty values in the request since they are no longer pending for writing into the changeset

Comment: Initially the Customizer was writing the dirty values into the changeset immediately upon a change, but this was very poor for performance. So that is why we have this pending `customized` state that gets sent in requests prior to it being written into the changeset after the autosave interval.

Comment: @WestonRuter How can I make the `get_theme_mod` return the customized state before `customize_save` happens?

Comment: @michael If you don't want to use jQuery Ajax prefiltering, then you'd need to detect when there are dirtyValues and if so, swap out the GET request for a POST one to then include the dirty values in a `customized` post var. You'd need to implement the logic found here: https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/fe5832ebdfade42930ad6aaa83b37fefe1d61ecb/src/wp-includes/js/customize-preview.js#L407-L458

Comment: I'd love to see a `fetch` wrapper in the Customizer preview which would translate GET requests into POST requests and automatically adding the `customize_changeset_uuid` param.

Comment: I'm working on a plugin for you to test.

Comment: @michael Give this a try: https://github.com/xwp/wp-customize-preview-fetch-api

Comment: @WestonRuter I really appreciate your help, but I can't even get it to work with jQuery. I must be missing a step or doing something wrong. Here's the bare code I use in a stripped down version https://gist.github.com/michaelnie/20e0962238da9cd82bffa75b491abf0a

Comment: @michael It turns out you discovered a bug! I've opened https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42162 with a patch to fix. Would you apply the patch to see if it fixes the issue you're experiencing? If so, I'll commit as part of 4.9. Once you've confirmed the fix, then here is a workaround you can apply to your JS until 4.9 is released: https://gist.github.com/westonruter/1095096e6bca16744421952a4da498c6#file-request-js-L13-L19

Comment: Here is the ticket for adding `fetch()` preview support to core: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42163

Comment: @WestonRuter I can confirm that the patch fixes the issue as well as the workaround. I can also confirm that your `Fetch` plugin works. So good! Thanks for your help to sort this out. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug in WordPress 4.8.2 which causes pending `customized` changes to not be injected into Ajax requests in the preview. This has been fixed in 4.9-alpha via [#42162](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42162). In the mean time, however, you can do a workaround to modify the requested `url` with logic like:

```
// Workaround defect introduced in WordPress 4.8.2 where preview nonce is not included in request.
if ( 'undefined' !== typeof _wpCustomizeSettings ) {
    urlParser = document.createElement( 'a' );
    urlParser.href = url;
    urlParser.search += '&customize_preview_nonce=' + _wpCustomizeSettings.nonce.preview;
    url = urlParser.href;
}
```